# Electronics project

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, breadboard

I am building a project for my college work which is used to detect the leakage of gas in house. The schematic diagram is given below.
[image: Schematic of the project][1](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/28Kq8RowMqM): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyo7G.jpg]
I removed the rectifier part because I am using a battery.
When I built the circuit in a simulation program the buzzer is not working.
[Wired connection of the project simulation](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/28Kq8RowMqM)
Is there anything wrong with the wired connection? If there is some error please help me to figure out. If the connections are proper then I shall start the project. I am a newbie and I need your guidance.

Comment: WHat kind of Buzzer is it? If the collector output is not <1V then it must be a magnetic type modelled which needs more current, whereas using a Piezo type runs on >1  mA current .  Changing the two R values to 50 Ohms is  drastic for power consumption but at least proves my speculation if it is a magnetic type.

Comment: A typical breadboard's "power rails" are split in the middle of each horizontal run and you need to jumper them over the gap.

Answer (score 2):

As brhans commented, your breadboard has the issue of not bridging the gap in the middle of the breadboard for the power and ground rails - they are not normally connected across this point. You need to add wires that connect them together!
[image: Breadboard with rail jumpers added]

Comment: I don't think your statement is true, that they are not **normally** connected across the middle. Most of the breadboards I have with me at the time **are** connected across...and there is a continuous red or blue stripe running alongside the holes. The graphic used in the "circuit design" program may look nothing like the breadboard that is actually in use.

Comment: But in this simulation the gaps between the power lines are connected internally. So I didn't use any kind of jumper wire in the simulation. I actual practice I shall connect the jumper wire across the lines.

Comment: I’m not seeing any red flags with your circuit, or anything that should cause any damage if you were to hook it up this way. Try assembling it and share your results.